# Best Practice Markup for HTML5 Banner Heading

Tags: html

I don’t mean a whole banner section or div, which can be identified with an ARIA attribute, but the banner title which identifies the site.

I have traditionally marked up a in a heading element. However, given how precious headings are, and how they affect the structure of a page, especially in HTML5, I wonder whether this is the best practice.

As far as I understand the main h1 element, typically, but not necessarily, inside the page header element should be distinct for each page. That rather rules it out for marking up a banner title.

I could put a new h1 inside a separate section, but in HTML5 that would limit the scope of the heading to the section.

I could put the title text inside a paragraph or a div, but that seems too miscellaneous.

So what element best contains the banner title text for the site?

Thanks